# Find string and replace another line in linux

Tags: linux, string, sed, replace

I have an xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Station name="XxXx" >
  <Inverter name="0701">
    <String name="07.01.01-1">
      <Converter sku="31570014-0900 A" sn="2116K000551" mac="548280000227" ts="01"/>
    </String>
    <String name="07.01.01-2">
      <Converter sku="31570014-0900 A" sn="1716K000232" mac="4482800000E8" ts="02"/>
    </String>
```

I need a script (or better one linux command) that can find in this file a String with name="07.01.01-1" for example, and change in the *next* line sn="2116K000551" to sn="11111111", and delete everything till the end of the line (means mac="xxx" ts="xx"), except closing tag "/>", and save this file. I'm trying to do it with sed, but not successfully for now. Is there a one linux command that can do it? I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet or something comparable).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way with **`xmlstarlet`** tool:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//String[contains(@name, "07.01.01-1") and ./Converter/@sn = "2116K000551"]
                  /Converter/@sn' -v 11111111 \
-d '//String[contains(@name,"07.01.01-1")]
    /Converter/@*[name()="mac" or name()="ts"]' file.xml
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Station name="XxXx">
  <Inverter name="0701">
    <String name="07.01.01-1">
      <Converter sku="31570014-0900 A" sn="11111111"/>
    </String>
    <String name="07.01.01-2">
      <Converter sku="31570014-0900 A" sn="1716K000232" mac="4482800000E8" ts="02"/>
    </String>
  </Inverter>
</Station>
```

---

To modify the file in-place - add `-L` option: `xmlstarlet ed -L -u ....`

Comment: Thank you! Looks like sed is not a right tool for this, but xmlstarlet looks more promising!